# connect cdrom to new motherboard

Tags: motherboard

[image]

Hi,
   I've bought new Intel DH77EB. replacing my older motherboard 915GAV.
   I thought of reusing older DVD writer. but i'm unable to connect the "40-Pin" data cable to the new board. am i missing something ?

Comment: Your motherboard uses SATA, not PATA. You'll need a converter if you really want to use the old 40p cable, or buy a SATA DVD writer instead

Comment: @CamilStaps I think that since (I suppose) the adapter would plug into the CDROM/DVDRW drive, rather than the motherboard. So it'd convert his CDROM fron 40-pin IDE/PATA,  into SATA. So he'd get an adapter and use a SATA cable and connect it to his motherboard.  I'd add, such adapters are probably very cheap. Maybe just a few dollars. some adapters maybe a bit more functional might go both ways. I haven't played with adapters much but what you want to do is trivial.

Comment: @CamilStaps thanks for your answer. I'll search for the specific adapter in the city.

Answer (score 5):

That 40 pins connector is the old [parallel ATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) connector.  It should look like the picture below.

[image: P ATA connector and plug]

In the last decade this older ATA version has been replaced by a new one, called [Serial-ATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA).

SATA can work on ancient ATA compatibility mode, and there are convertors to connect old devices to the new connectors. These are relative cheap, starting around 5 euros.

[image: Example ATA to SATA]

If you really want to use the older DVD drive then it might be the cheapest way to buy one of these. Alternatives are:

- getting a new SATA based writer,
- getting a PATA controller (a new card to plug into one of the PCIe slots)
- Or just skipping the drive. Personally I only needed a CDROM once in the last four years. Everything else (including installation ISO's) can be done with pen drives.